# Why facebook socialite login not working suddenly?

Tags: laravel

I am implementing a website and i implemented a facebook login with the help of socialite package. It was working fine but suddenly it starts saying  ***GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException***

```
Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me?access_token=EAAJWzLrZAbJ8BAHBPV56l7CG5THpGlgaKWDJY6AYoZACvMv9GjmjQ0PBRjbdZBFbTqpM5wuuo30hvnALWLBKpmgl7k82MR2nXmbMtWQLodxoNNreiz2crqnYbPYltmUKaM8IJg5aw9nUIgchh84LOBJ8XL2gBe279o4rlRamgZDZD&fields=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=66c071ea673cecd2df8d35c9dad4aaffb4dad595fb03628898b0e6078186b143` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) Missing Permissions","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AUoFNG89hfmlPG13WW8rbF (truncated...)
```

I haven't touched this code but ti shows me this error.

Comment: Can someone say what might be the possible problem?

Comment: Guys why just vote down. I have encountered with same problem. Please explain before give vote down maybe it can be easy problem for you but we need argument  and explanation.

Comment: Its okay to Vote down but at least mention something. I literally got no idea about this and maybe the reason why i couldn't explain better. This was working yesterday but not today.

Comment: same here. 403 Forbidden` response: {"error":{"message":"(#200) Missing Permissions"

Comment: same here getting missing permission error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My apps throw the same error. It seems to be an issue on Facebooks side. A fix is already in the works.

https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/817076795498952/

Answer (score 1):

Though this issue is fixed, you can try this for any future issues.

Goto vendor->laravel->socialite->src->Two->FacebookProvider.php

Find this line 28 and replace:

> protected $fields = ['name', 'email'];

This is for facebook new policy. Socialite requested for more fields like gender, link.